# Thermodynamic quantities of thin soap film on wire frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, surface-tension

Here is a question I am trying to solve. Sorry for the highlighting, it is not relevant.

[image]

Here are my answers.

For a), I would write $dE = dQ + dW$, following the first principle of thermodynamics. And for $dW$, I would write $dW=Fdx = 2l \sigma dx$. But I am a bit worried about the $T$ dependency of $\sigma$... Is my answer fine ?

For b), I fix $E(0)$ to be equal to zero, and I compute $\Delta E = E(x) = Q + 2\sigma l x = Q + 2 (\sigma_0 - \alpha T_0) l x$.

For c), I just have $W = 2l\sigma x$.

I don't really get the point of the question and I have the feeling I miss something important, especially because some questions seems redundant. Can anybody please help me ? Thanks.

Comment: very confusing question!

Comment: I bet you can think of a more descriptive title. Check [these tips on writing good titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles).